# ExtJS 5 chart series renderer

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs5

I have a grid and a line chart. Both of them use one store. I use grid column *renderer()* function which looks like this:

```
renderer: function(value){
   return value;
}
```

to change the data depending on some conditions(delta, ratios etc). I also want to reflect these actions in my chart. I guess I should set series *renderer()* but it doesn't have value as parameter:

```
renderer: function (sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
 if (config.type === 'marker') {
     return { strokeStyle: (index % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : 'black') };
 }
}
```

Is it possible to implement rendering such as in grid to change my plot but **without changing actual data in store**?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the `value` you are searching can be found in the `rendererData` parameter, which is an object that contains the property `angleField`. I don't know whether changing it there affects the chart, but I would guess so (just like the `metaData` parameter in the grid renderer affects the rendering of the grid).

BUT:

Renderers only change the **display** of certain data. The underlying values stay the same, which may affect all kinds of data manipulation, like grouping, sorting etc.

If you really want to change the values based on conditions, you are better off if you extend the model, adding `calculate`d columns, which do not persist, and set the `dataIndex`es of your `gridcolumn`s accordingly (likewise for the chart).

I am not sure whether renderers can affect the size of the slices in a pie chart; but I am sure that if you (for example) sort the store by the slice size, changing the value in the renderer will not affect how the slices are ordered in the chart.

That said, it's up to you; my remark is for sake of completeness only.

Comment: I read that 'angleField' is a config for polar chart. But nevertheless I got value in this way 'rendererData.store.data.items[index].data.value'. Hovewer I still don't know how to return this value in order to commit visual changes in my chart. 

@Alexander Also I can't use 'convert'(or calculate) function in model because I need to have access to all data that I need before loading it to store. (E.g. to compare value with value from previous object or with first object from set)